# Is it a bad practice to generate a certificate chain with the same private key

Tags: cryptography, certificate, x509

I am generating a certificate chain with a root CA, an intermediate CA, and a leaf certificate using the same signing key coming from a hardware security module. In all tutorials I've seen online, the 3 certificates are always generated using different keys. However, is it a *bad practice* to re-use a private key, which is stored securely, for all certificates in the certificate chain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bad practice which could lead to severe security issues and invalidates the concept of PKI hierarchy. Let's imagine a scenario in which your private key is compromised, in this case you will have to revoke 3 certificates including your root certificate authority.

A good practice is,

1. Use separate keys for each entity and CA
2. Keep your root-ca offline
3. Use your intermediate CA to issue the end entity certificates

By this way, if one of the key is compromised ( entity ) , you can revoke the certificate using Certificate revocation lists.

Comment: I am curious if this holds true in a situation where the private key is unleakable, i.e. it's inside a FIPS 140-3 hardware security module.

Comment: these rules apply regardless how the key is stored and how secure it is. And you need to understand that when leaf certificate is used, it must have access to HSM. Using same key in all certificates in the chain makes zero sense. You don't need so much certificates, create just one. It would be better if you explain the goal you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @Crypt32. I need to use a root CA, intermediate CA and a leaf cert because that is what the infrastructure for my project requires but I wasn't sure whether 1 key suffices when stored securely in a FIPS-validated HSM. If the rules require 3 regardless of the situation, then I'll use 3.